# How to call C function placed in .cu file from c file?

Tags: c, cuda, linker

I need call C function placed in cuda(.cu) file from C file(.c). I have hierarchy that looks like that.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dbgHelpers.h"
#include "arffReader.h"
#include "CPU_k_means.h"
#include "CUDA_k_means.h"

#include "defines.h"

int main() {
    //actions
    uint cudaTime = runCudaKMeans(h_objects, objectsNum, parametersNum, clustersNum, repeatesNum, streamsNum);
    //actions
    return 0;
}
```

CUDA_k_means.cu

```
#include "CUDA_k_means.h"

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
#include "dbgHelpers.h"
}

__constant__ uint d_CLUST_NUM;
__constant__ uint d_OBJ_NUM;
__constant__ uint d_PARAMS_NUM;
__constant__ uint d_OBJ_PER_STREAM;
__constant__ uint d_OBJ_FOR_LAST_STREAM;

extern __shared__ uint sharedData[];

__global__ void calcDistances(ptype* d_objects, ptype* d_clustersCenters, ptype* d_distances)
{
    //algorithm
}

__global__ void clusterize(ptype* d_distances, uint* d_clustersMap)
{
    //algorithm
}

//and more kernels

uint runCudaKMeans(ptype* h_objects, uint objectsNum, uint parametersNum, uint clustersNum, uint repeatesNum, uint streamsNum) {
    //algorithm
    calcDistances<<32, 32>>();
    //and so on
}
```

CUDA_k_means.h

```
#ifndef CUDA_K_MEANS_H_
#define CUDA_K_MEANS_H_

#include "defines.h"

uint runCudaKMeans(ptype* h_objects, uint objectsNum, uint parametersNum, uint clustersNum, uint repeatesNum, uint streamsNum);

#endif
```

I can't link it correctly. NSight return this error.

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/nvcc --cudart static --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_20 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -link -o  "lab5"  ./CPU_k_means.o ./CUDA_k_means.o ./arffReader.o ./dbgHelpers.o ./main.o   
./main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text.startup+0x8c): undefined reference to `runCudaKMeans'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lab5] Error 1
```

Don't know what to do. I tried different combinations of "extern C", but without any success. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.

In CUDA_k_means.cu file.

First line with

```
#include "CUDA_k_means.h"
```

need to be removed.

In the same file function need to be marked as "extern "C" so it will look like.

```
extern "C" uint runCudaKMeans(ptype* h_objects, uint objectsNum, uint parametersNum, uint clustersNum, uint repeatesNum, uint streamsNum)
```

In CUDA_k_means.h if you wan't include it in main.c function declaration must look like

```
extern uint runCudaKMeans(ptype* h_objects, uint objectsNum, uint parametersNum, uint clustersNum, uint repeatesNum, uint streamsNum)
```

Can't completely explain how is it work. If someone know, you could explain it here.

Comment: A full explanation can be found in the linked duplicate